# How to send multiple checkbox values in single object through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I have a form with 4 different checkboxes with ids namely filter_AFFILIATION_1, filter_AFFILIATION_2 and so on till 4. I am trying to send the checked checkboxes values to the server dynamically by using an ajax call. Here is my code:

```
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){   
    var ids = ['filter_AFFILIATION_1','filter_AFFILIATION_2','filter_AFFILIATION_3','filter_AFFILIATION_4'];    
    for(var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){
      if(document.getElementById(ids[i]).checked === true){
      var data = {};
      data['request'+i] =  $('#'+ ids[i]).val();            
      console.log(data);
        }
    }

     $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', 
            url: Routing.generate('listingpage'),
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            data: data,        
        success: function(result,status,xhr){
            console.log(result);
        }
```

If you look at

```
data['request'+i] =  $('#'+ ids[i]).val();            
      console.log(data);
```

part of the code, the output of console.log if I click

1. **Only first checkbox**:

   `{request0: "1"}`
2. **First and then second checkbox**:

   `{request0: "1"}`

   `{request1: "2"}`
3. **First and then second and then 3rd checkbox**:

   `{request0: "1"}`

   `{request1: "2"}`

   `{request2: "3"}`
4. **First then second, then third and then uncheck second checkbox**:

   `{request0: "1"}`

   `{request2: "3"}`

Now my problem is that I want to send the data as a single object rather than multiple objects such as if the user clicks first checkbox and then second the output of console.log(data) should be

```
 `{request0: "1", request1: "2"}`
```

I've tried a lot of different methods but nothing seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried data.push() ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting your `data` object. What you want is to declare the `data` object outside the `for` loop, and then add new key-value pairs to the pre-existing object within the loop:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    var ids = ['filter_AFFILIATION_1', 'filter_AFFILIATION_2', 'filter_AFFILIATION_3', 'filter_AFFILIATION_4'];

    // Create object outside of for loop
    var data = {};

    // Iterate through ids array
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {

        if (document.getElementById(ids[i]).checked === true) {

            // Create new key in pre-existing data object and assign value
            data['request' + i] = $('#' + ids[i]).val();

        }
    }

    // Just logging, to check
    console.log(data);

    // Request
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: Routing.generate('listingpage'),
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        data: data,
        success: function(result, status, xhr) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @utkarsh2k2 No problem, glad my answer helped :)